# Should I create a separate webpage for related keywords?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, keywords, backlinks, webpage

I am setting up a website for a dentist in Turkey, and I'm not sure whether or not I should set up two different webpages for "Dental Veneers Turkey" and "Laminate Veneers Turkey".

They seem to be referring to closely related but different things, and I'm not sure if it would be more beneficial (advantageous in terms of backlinks) to set up different pages for them or just write about them in the same webpage.

I see people both creating different webpages for them and getting ranked for them with the same webpage. This is not the first time I've faced this dilemma and would like to finally figure this out. Is there a method to determine when it would be better to go with one of these two options? I think it would be best to create a single webpage for them just because it seems more intuitive, but I'd be welcoming of any guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Think about the intent of the user. Content that is about the same thing but varies in user intent is not considered duplicative.

In your case, I would recommend an overall page about Dental Veneers because the intent is the same, the variation in searches seems to be about different types and making a decision.

I would recommend a page that flows something like this:

- Types of Veneers
- Why Do People Get Veneers?
- How Are Veneers Placed on Teeth?
- Side Effects & Risks of Veneers
- How Much Do Veneers Cost?
- Veneers vs. Other Dental Treatments
- FAQ about Veneers
- Call to Action (Request Consultation, Information Packet, etc)

A page like this displaying high [E-A-T/YMYL](https://lilyray.nyc/e-a-t-expertise-authoritativeness-trustworthiness/) would also naturally attract quality backlinks.